# "Mobile sliding menu" module for my Drupal Commerce kickstart site

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, mmenu, commerce, commerce-kickstart

I need to install "Mobile sliding menu" module for my Drupal Commerce kickstart site. I install the free version of http://mmenu.frebsite.nl, but my status report says "The Mmenu library was not detected".Do I need to buy the license?

Comment: See this issue on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2308145 There are some suggestions within the issue.